# Apple Mail incoming mail notification

Tags: mail.app, notifications, ms-office

When you get a new mail in Entourage then a small window appears with some basic info about the new mail you receveid. Is it possible to do the same thing with Apple Mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Growl and the GrowlMail plugin, simply click to view the message, and it's free! http://growl.info/

[image: GrowlMail screenshot]

Comment: Thanx did the job perfectly! Just one detail I have problems with that in my notification the date shows up which is a bit of an overkill in information. Is it possible to remove this information?

Comment: @elhombre GrowlMail does not do this on my installation, and I couldn't find a preference which would cause it to do so (or not do so, as you require).

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Mail.appetizer](http://bronsonbeta.com/mailappetizer/) before and it was my favorite of all the mail notification apps I've tried.  It's not yet compatible officially with Snow Leopard, but there are [development versions](http://www.bronsonbeta.com/mailappetizer/developmentsnapshot/) available that will probably work (link from [their twitter account](http://twitter.com/BronsonBeta)).

Note that in recent versions of OS X, Mail requires that plugins list the specific versions of it that they support; they can't just say they're compatible with anything newer than a certain version.  The current development version of Mail.appetizer is for 10.6.5 and Mail 4.4; if you're running 10.6.6, that might be a problem.  See [this OSXHints article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100823103751355) for a way to fix it.